# Update NSMenuItem while the host menu is shown

Tags: cocoa, macos, nsmenuitem

I have an `NSMenuItem` that I need to update to show a progress (like Time machine does with it's backup). The problem is that when I set a new `title` on that `NSMenuItem` and the `title` is not changing.

It is in fact changing when I close and reopen the menu, but I want to update it while the user is looking at it.

I also tried remove an item and re-inserting it with no result.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This actually works with no additional effort if your updating code runs in the [run loop mode](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html) which is used during menu tracking.  This is `NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode`, but you probably just want to use `NSRunLoopCommonModes` so the menu item title is correct when the menu is pulled down.

Here's a simple example of a menu item `foo` that counts the number of seconds since the app launched:

```
- (void)doStuff;
{
    static int i = 0;
    [foo setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", ++i]];
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification;
{
    NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:
                                [self methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(doStuff)]];
    [invocation setTarget:self];
    [invocation setSelector:@selector(doStuff)];
    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:[NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1 invocation:invocation repeats:YES] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
}
```

Comment: Very valuable answer. This is a very common problem for folks the first time they encounter the menu runloop.

Comment: You're absolutely right Nicholas, was trying to do it with `performSelector:afterDelay:` which run on `NSDefaultRunLoopMode`. Thanks a lot for your answer.